# How to build a vector of strings of filenames in a directory and its subfolders?

Tags: c++

I'm currently using the following code:

```
std::vector<std::string> paths;    

std::string path = "Assets/";
for (const auto& entry : std::filesystem::directory_iterator(path)) {
    paths.push_back(entry.path().string());
}
```

But, it ignores the subfolders in the `Assets/` folder. How can I make it keep track of all the files in subfolders?

eg. Let's say the `Assets/` directory looked like this:

```
Assets/
---image01.png
---image02.png
---somefile.txt
---subfolder/
------example.png
---anotherfolder/
------anotherfile.txt
```

I would want the vector to look like this:

```
Assets/image01.png
Assets/image02.png
Assets/somefile.txt
Assets/subfolder/example.png
Assets/anotherfolder/anotherfile.txt
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a [`std::recursive_directory_iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/recursive_directory_iterator) to get the paths of the nested directories:

```
for (const auto& entry : std::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator(path)) {
    paths.push_back(entry.path().string());
}
```

Also, instead of storing the `path`s as `string`s, you could store them directly, like this:

```
std::vector<std::filesystem::path> paths;
```

You can convert these to `string`s later if you need, but you can do other things to them as well.